# How can I customize the 'From' field when sending and email with PHP's mail() function?

Tags: email, php

Consider the 'From' column in gmail. Sometimes this column says things like `<info@company.com>`, but it usually will say something like `Company Name`. How can I get my emails to say `My Company` in the 'From' column when viewing the email inbox. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$to = recipient@some_domain.com;
$subject = 'You have mail!';
$message = 'This is my message.';
$headers = 'From: me@my_company.com';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

In gmail the 'From' column of the users inbox will say 'me', and in yahoo it will say 'me@my_company.com'. I want it to say 'My Company'. I have tried this:

```
$headers = 'From: "My Company" <me@my_company.com>';
```

but it doesn't work. How can I get it to say 'My Company' in the 'From' field when a user receives one of my emails? Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using sendmail, in addition to standard headers, you can specify the `-f` option to set the envelope sender address:

```
$headers  = 'From: "My Company" <me@my_company.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: me@my_company.com' . "\r\n";

mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-fme@my_company.com');
```

This helped me in the past to solve the same problem you're having.

Comment: Should there be a space after the `-f`?

Comment: Nah you don't need a space after `-f`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$headers="From: Your Company\r\nReply-To: yourEmail@your.com";
```

Comment: That didn't work. It lists the name of the currently logged in user in the 'From' field, and the email address is listed as 'my_name@my_web_hosting_company.com'.